# I am trying to understand how to choose number of Azure IOT Hubs in a scenario where I have variety of devices sending variety of data

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to understand on do I need to choose individual IOT HUB based on device category.

For Example I have devices sending GPS info.
Devices send stock info
Devices sending quality info.
Devices sending security info.
Devices sending fire safety info.

Each of the above category devices send versatile data in versatile format. In this scenario is it a best option to configure multiple IOT hubs or one IOT hub is suffice.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

As the IoT Hub is totally agnostic to the actual data that you are sending, you would not need to have separate IoT Hubs per use case. You can still connect all the devices to one IoT Hub and then [route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c) the telemetry data, for example [based on on device properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax), to different downstream processing steps.

You might still want to use multiple IoT Hubs but mainly then for either scaling reasons or for geographical distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. So What I understand is multiple iot hubs are required either when go for scaling or we want to have IOT hubs geographically co located with IOT devices. In my scenario I can configure IOT routes to separate the telemetry based on the device type.

Comment: yes. Regarding scaling, one IoT Hub can scale to millions of messages so when you just start with it, you are probably safe for a while with just one instance

Comment: One million devices is the standard limit. You can get that increased by request. Routing may help here but you will need to pay for those endpoints. Alternatively you could pipe it all into a single application and have it decide what to do with each message.